# Unable to share video's URL on Facebook via Android Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, facebook, url, video, share

I need to share URL on video resource programmatically.
Example of URL is http://flash.video.worldnow.com/kold/KOLD_20110714204221200AA.mp4

I use Intent.ACTION_SEND for it:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test subject");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://flash.video.worldnow.com/kold/KOLD_20110714204221200AA.mp4");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,
                "Share URL"));
```

Facebook android application can't handle the URL and shows following error:

**"flash objects must have the 'swfsrc' and 'imgsrc' attributes"**

How to avoid the error? How to put required attributes into "text/plain" message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked at Facebook application sources (ShareLinkActivity) and didn't found any possibility to add required fields to share request. Content of intent extra parameter Intent.EXTRA_TEXT only is used.

Answer (score 2):

After several hours of trying to find out how to make it work for uploading and sharing video on facebook, youtube, instagram and whatsapp. this is the code that worked for me. Uploading recorded video from your application to social media applications

try using ContentValues when dealing with videos and specifying MediaStore.Video.Media.Data in the content.

```
ContentValues content = new ContentValues(4);
        content.put(Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED,
        System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
        content.put(Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
        content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, "your_path_to_video");
        ContentResolver resolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, content);

        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("video/*");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Title");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"share:")); `
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this page [here.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments/) It looks like it wants the swfsrc and imgsrc encoded in a JSON-encoded array. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't use JSON request. I need to use common Android functionality for sending(i.e. Intent.ACTION_SEND). In this case the same Intent can be handled by any social client(e.g. Facebook, Twitter etc.) and also can be sent via SMS, MMS and E-Mail. I need to find a way how to put mentioned above required for Facebook fields in simple text message and share it via Intent.

Comment: You can put a JSON-encoded array in as extra text in an intent! With Facebook the stream attachment is an array of structured data that defines the post!

Comment: Content Intent.EXTRA_TEXT can't be JSON in my case. This text should be still valid for sharing on a Twitter as well. What another extra parameter name should be used to put attachment into intent extra? I've tryed to put it with name "attachment" with no success: sendIntent.putExtra("attachment", "{\"media\":[{\"type\": \"flash\",\"swfsrc\": \"" + "flash.video.worldnow.com/kold/KOLD_20110718232729103AC.mp4"; + "\", \"imgsrc\":\"icanhascheezburger.files.wordpress.com/2009/04/…\"}]}");
FYI:paramenter name Intent.EXTRA_TEXT was also tried and it is also ignored by Facebook's ShareUrlActivity

Answer (score 0):

I searched this for almost 7 hours, following is the **only solution that worked** for me perfectly .

```
 File filePath = filesList[position]; 
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(filesList[position].getAbsolutePath())));  //optional//use this when you want to send an image
            shareIntent.setType("video/mp4");
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));
```