# How to share video to Facebook on Android

Tags: android, android-facebook

I try to take a reference from [Facebook integration in android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)

Here is my step

**Step1:** Try to import Facebook SDK

```
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
...
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
...
    }
```

**Step2:** Set the code on Manifests,333991926986699 is **My Facebook app_id**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
....
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider333991926986699"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true" />
....
    </application>
```

And then about sharing video code from official is like this:

```
Uri videoFileUri = ...
ShareVideo = new ShareVideo.Builder()
        .setLocalUrl(videoUrl)
        .build();
ShareVideoContent content = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
        .setVideo(video)
        .build();
```

I have no idea how to let it work .

This is my video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJCvu6vqWf4). Can anyone teach me what next should I do?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is i try to share code:

```
shareButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.shareButton);

        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Uri videoFileUri=Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeLqNx7dMBM");
                ShareVideo shareVideo=new ShareVideo.Builder()
                        .setLocalUrl(videoFileUri)
                        .build();
                //There is no use by content
                ShareVideoContent content=new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
                        .setVideo(shareVideo)
                        .build();
            }
        });
```

Comment: do you want to upload that video or do you want to share the link for your video?

Comment: I want to share the link .

Comment: ok, I see. And what do you mean with 'I have no idea to let it work'? Does it throw an error? Maybe you should post your code how you integrated the facebook sample into your app

Comment: There is no chance for error , i think that my `content` is no using .   I update my code about try to share.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431974/android-intent-share-to-share-a-video-url-on-facebook

Comment: do you not have the facebook app installed O.o

Comment: Thanks for the link , i had tried it before about that answer , it's no working . And yes , i have the facebook app on test device.

Comment: Uri videoFileUri = ...
ShareVideo = new ShareVideo.Builder()
        .setLocalUrl(videoUrl)
        .build();
ShareVideoContent content = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
        .setVideo(video)
        .build();

Comment: this is from here > https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: so if ur video is more than 12mb in size u share link or u share video itself

Comment: and use url builder to make url from local video path

Comment: omg, wait, so you want to share a video from youtube to facebook?

Comment: ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJCvu6vqWf4"))
        .build(); should work wonders

Comment: Thank you , but i just want to share the video link from my app to facebook not from youtube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to share a link but you are using the code to share a video which is on your device.

Please have a look at

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

and try to use the code for sharing a link

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
        .build();
```

Please take into account that you have to use the Facebook Share Button. Please see at the bottom of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

```
ShareButton shareButton = (ShareButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_share_button);
shareButton.setShareContent(content);
```

You cannot use the standard Android Button

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but i try to use this code for a button , it's no working , do i miss something ?

Comment: I mean it doesn't show any layout or dialog for sharing video